# Rotating object around one of its points

Tags: java

I have a problem where I have to create a random object(figure) and I have to rotate it. In class, we created a code where we rotate the whole object with this code

```
 int count = Integer.parseInt(jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString());
    double alfa = Math.toRadians(Float.parseFloat(jTextField1.getText()));
     for (int i=0;i<count;i++){
         int x=(int)Math.round(P.x[i]*Math.cos(alfa)-P.y[i]*Math.sin(alfa));
         int y=(int)Math.round(P.x[i]*Math.sin(alfa)+P.y[i]*Math.cos(alfa));
         P.x[i]=x;
         P.y[i]=y;

     }
```

But I have to modify this code, to make it rotate around a specific point of that object, if previously that point was somewhere outside of an object, this time, it has to be a point of an object. [Picture of object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kICuK.jpg) I have to rotate all the red points around blue point. I have a radio button in my form, where I can select a specific point of the object, where then with mouse click I can change coordinates of the point, but I don't know how to get X and Y coordinates without using a mouse to use this formula:

> x1=x-centerX;
>
> y1=y-centerY;
>
> x2=x1*Math.cos(alpha)+y1*Math.sin(alpha);
>
> y2=x1*Math.sin(alpha)-y1.Math.cos(alpha);
>
> x3=x2+centerX;
>
> y3=y2+centerY;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is rotating around the origin, that is the point whose coordinates are x=0, y=0.

```
     int x=(int)Math.round(P.x[i]*Math.cos(alfa)-P.y[i]*Math.sin(alfa));
```

You now need to rotate it around some other point, let's call it XX, YY

```
     int x=(int)Math.round((P.x[i]-XX)*Math.cos(alfa)-(P.y[i]-YY)*Math.sin(alfa));
```

And when you've got x and y, then you need to add in the original point:

```
     P.x[i]=XX+x;
```

I've only done the "x" side of things here and leave "y" as an exercise for the reader.  It should be quite straightforward.

Comment: I solved this problem using `if (jRadioButton12.isSelected()) {xC=P.x[0]; yC=P.y[0];} ` and then I got the Center coordinates, which I used to implement in the formula, but in `P.x[i]=XX+x;` I was able to shorten it like this `P.x[i]=x;`
Thank you for your help! :)